# Ubuntu Xenial PHP5.6 Userdir not working

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have the following problem.

I Installed different PHP versions (php5.6, php7.0, php7.1) for testing using the `ondrej/php` PPA.

I can enable and disable the different versions without problems for my Apache using these commands:

```
a2dismod php5.6
a2enmod php7.0
service apache2 restart
```

... an so on

But: PHP is not working in my userdir (`/home/*/public_html`), but only on version 5.6, versions 7.0 and 7.1 are working without problems.

I also tried to uncomment the line `php_admin_flag engine Off` in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.6.conf`. But it's still not working.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How did you enable the userdir configuration for Apache?

Comment: @muru Userdir is enabled via `a2enmod userdir`. Also the `userdir.load` and `userdir.conf` is loading and working. I also tried to set `php_admin_flag engine On`, but it's still not working.